# Trying to combine the entered input value captured by event.target.value in reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I am trying to retrieve the combined input value entered by the user via event.target.value and then putting it into an array like below, but what I get is each character enterd by the user and is getting stored in an array.

```
 handleChangeHN(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let { nameArray } = this.state;
    this.setState({ nameArray: nameArray.concat(event.target.value;) })
    console.log(`Entered Name :`, nameArray);
  }
```

```
Actual output is like:
Entered Name : 
Array []
Entered Name : 
Array [ "t" ]
Entered Name : 
Array [ "t", "te" ]
Entered Name : 
Array(3) [ "t", "te", "tes" ]
Entered Name : 
Array(4) [ "t", "te", "tes", "test" ]
Entered Name : 
Array(5) [ "t", "te", "tes", "test", "testi" ]
Entered Name : 
Array(6) [ "t", "te", "tes", "test", "testi", "testin" ]

Expected output:
Entered Name : 
Array(0) [ "testing1", "testing2" and so on ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the handleChange function is called it creates a new array and concats old array with the newly entered input so you get output like this

```
Array [ "t" ]
Array [ "t", "te" ]


Array(3) [ "t", "te", "tes" ]
```

create the array outside the handleChange fucntion and try setting state like this

```
this.setState({nameArray:e.target.value})
```

Comment: The nameArray is already declared/created in a state which is outside handleChange function. Can you please be more precise. Also, when I do this.setState({nameArray:e.target.value}) it does not treat it as an array and just overrides the next input value.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the handleChangeHN function in onChange event.also pass the array index.
Let assume you have multiple input field and you want to store the value of each field in one array. then first input field value will be store in 0 index of array.Then write `onChange={(e)=>this.handleChangeHN(e,0)}` liek this and write handleChange function as follow.

```
 handleChangeHN(event,arrayIndex) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let { nameArray } = this.state;
  nameArray[arrayIndex] = event.target.value;
  this.setState({ nameArray},()=>{console.log(`Entered Name :`, nameArray);})

}
```

Comment: You understood it right, but this solution does not work for me somehow.

Comment: what is the output you get?

Comment: Please see below output.
Now the second input value is not being appended rather replacing the first one.

```
Array [ "T" ] 
Array [ "Te" ]
Array [ "Tes" ]  
Array [ "Test" ]
Createdevice.jsx:84
Array:  
Array [ "S" ]
Array [ "Sa" ] 
Array [ "Sam" ] 
Array [ "Samp" ]
Array [ "Sampl" ]
Array [ "Sample" ]
````

Comment: if you pass different index for every field than you will get desire output